# eval printf works from command line but not in script

Tags: shell

When I run the following command in a terminal it works, but not from a script:

```sh
eval $(printf "ssh foo -f -N "; \
       for port in $(cat ~/bar.json | grep '_port' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'); do \
           printf "-L $port:127.0.0.1:$port ";\
       done)
```

The error I get tells me that printf usage is wrong, as if the -L argument within quotes would've been an argument to printf itself.
I was wondering why that is the case. Am I missing something obvious?

__

Context (in case my issue is an XY problem): I want to start and connect to a jupyter kernel running on a remote computer. To do so I wrote a small script that

1. sends a command per ssh for the remote to start the kernel
2. copies via scp a configuration file that I can use to connect to the kernel from my local computer
3. reads the configuration file and opens appropriate ssh tunnels between local and remote

For those not familiar with jupyter, a configuration file (bar.json) looks more or less like the following:

```
{
  "shell_port": 35932,
  "iopub_port": 37145,
  "stdin_port": 42704,
  "control_port": 39329,
  "hb_port": 39253,
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "key": "4cd3e12f-321bcb113c204eca3a0723d9",
  "transport": "tcp",
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "kernel_name": ""
}
```

And so, in my command above, the printf statement creates an ssh command with all the 5 `-L` port forwarding for my local computer to connect to the remote, and eval should run that command. Here's the full script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Tell remote to start a jupyter kernel.
ssh foo -t 'python -m ipykernel_launcher -f ~/bar.json' &
# Wait a bit for the remote kernel to launch and write conf. file
sleep 5
# Copy the conf. file from remote to local.
scp foo:~/bar.json ~/bar.json
# Parse the conf. file and open ssh tunnels.
eval $(printf "ssh foo -f -N "; \
       for port in $(cat ~/bar.json | grep '_port' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'); do \
           printf "-L $port:127.0.0.1:$port ";\
       done)
```

Finally, `jupyter console --existing ~/foo.json` connects to remote.

Comment: Quoting doesn't affect whether something is considered a flag. If the same code works in a terminal, you're probably using Zsh which accepts `printf '-foo'`, while running the script with `bash` or `dash` which does not. You can use `printf -- '-foo'` when the format string starts with a dash. But yeah, don't bother with eval/grep/printf when you can use robust `jq` and arrays.

Comment: BTW, [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) goes into best practices around dynamically constructing commands, and is well worth a read. (It never discusses `eval` -- but reasons not to use it are the topic of [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @that other guy says, bash's printf builtin barfs on `printf "-L ..."`. It thinks you're passing it a `-L` option. You can fix it by adding `--`:

```
printf -- "-L $port:127.0.0.1:$port "
```

Let's make that:

```
printf -- '-L %s:127.0.0.1:%s ' "$port" "$port"
```

But since we're here, we can do a lot better. First, let's not process JSON with basic shell tools. We don't want to rely on it being formatting a certain way. We can use [**jq**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries | map(select(.key | test(".*_port"))) | .[].value' bar.json
35932
37145
42704
39329
39253
```

Here we use `to_entries` to convert each field to a key-value pair. Then we *select* entries where the `.key` matches the regex `.*_port`. Finally we extract the corresponding `.value`s.

We can get rid of `eval` by constructing the `ssh` command in an array. It's always good to avoid `eval` when possible.

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t ports < <(jq -r 'to_entries | map(select(.key | test(".*_port"))) | .[].value' bar.json)

ssh=(ssh foo -f -N)
for port in "${ports[@]}"; do ssh+=(-L "$port:127.0.0.1:$port"); done
"${ssh[@]}"
```

Comment: Re: showcasing best practices around array usage, it'd be better to use `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a ports < <(jq ... && printf '\0')` to avoid the issues discussed in [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: @dangom, is your script flagged executable with `chmod +x`? If not, zsh may be invoking it directly on account of the `execv` syscall failing.

Comment: @dangom, ...that said, if you wanted to collect some data we could use to have less guesswork involved, comparing `echo "Bash version: $BASH_VERSION"` between the two scenarios might help.

Comment: The only reason I was suggesting `read -a` instead of `readarray` was the OP being on a Mac, thus having the OS-vendor-provided bash be 3.x... but yes, better. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks. The script is flagged executable. The BASH_VERSION prints 5.0.2. Thanks for taking the time to help out and for your explanations

Comment: Just to be clear, it prints 5.0.2 *in both cases*, the working one and the broken one as well?